# VBA Do loop repeats same record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So my problem this time is that my do loop doesn't seem to be progressing through the recordset, instead using the same criteria for every SQL event in the loop.  I want it to cycle through the rs for the form, using the criteria from each record to determine the match on a separate table and adjust values there accordingly.

Immediate window when running the loop on test data looks like this...

```
    UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [Bid] = [Bid] - 281, [Sold] = [Sold] + 281 WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '16-4021A';
    UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [Bid] = [Bid] - 281, [Sold] = [Sold] + 281 WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '16-4021A';
    UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [Bid] = [Bid] - 281, [Sold] = [Sold] + 281 WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '16-4021A';
    UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [Bid] = [Bid] - 281, [Sold] = [Sold] + 281 WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '16-4021A';
    UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [Bid] = [Bid] - 281, [Sold] = [Sold] + 281 WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '16-4021A';
```

Both the numerical values and the '16-4021A' at the end should be changing every record.

Here's my code.

```vb
   Private Sub btnConfirm_Click()

   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String

   On Error GoTo EH

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    If MsgBox("All records have been saved.  Do you wish to exit?/ Todos los registros han sido guardados. ¿Deseas salir?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblCalOrderShorts"
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    If Me.QuantityHv <> 0 Then
        If Me.WithBracket = -1 Then
            strSQL = "UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [Bid] = [Bid] - " & Me.QuantityHv & ", [Sold] = [Sold] + " & Me.QuantityHv & " WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '" & Me.Cardone & "';"
            Debug.Print strSQL
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        ElseIf Me.WithBracket = 0 Then
            strSQL = "UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [WOBracketBid] = [WOBracketBid] - " & Me.QuantityHv & ", [WOBracketSold] = [WOBracketSold] + " & Me.QuantityHv & " WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '" & Me.Cardone & "';"
            Debug.Print strSQL
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        ElseIf Me.WithBracket = Null Then
            strSQL = "UPDATE [Caliper Master] SET [BracketBid] = [BracketBid] - " & Me.QuantityHv & ", [BracketSold] = [BracketSold] + " & Me.QuantityHv & " WHERE [A1CardoneItemNo] = '" & Me.Cardone & "';"
            Debug.Print strSQL
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        ElseIf Me.WithBracket <> -1 Or 0 Or Null Then
            MsgBox "Invalid value for bracket status./ No esta correcto el estado por bracket."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf Me.QuantityHv = 0 Then
    End If
    If Me.QuantityHv < Me.QuantityNd Then
        If Not IsNull(DLookup("tblCalOrderShorts", "MSysObjects", "Name = 'tblCalOrderShorts'")) Then
            db.Execute "CREATE TABLE tblCalOrderShorts(Cardone CHAR, QuantityNd INTEGER, QuantityHv INTEGER, Short INTEGER) "
        End If
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblCalOrderShorts(Cardone, QuantityNd, QuantityHv, Short) VALUES('" & Me.Cardone & "', " & Me.QuantityNd & ", " & Me.QuantityHv & ", " & Me.QuantityNd - Me.QuantityHv & ");"
        Debug.Print strSQL
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.OpenForm "subCaliperOrderDetails", , , "[Cardone] =" & Me!subCaliperOrderDetails.Form!Cardone, , acDialog
Forms!subCaliperOrderDetails.Form.Requery
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCaliperPack"
   Else
   Exit Sub
   End If

   EH:
   Select Case Err
       Case 3376
            Resume Next
       Case 7874
            Resume Next
       Case 2465
            Resume Next
       Case Else
           MsgBox "Run Time Error " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.DESCRIPTION
   End Select

   End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason for looping through the records instead of executing just three `UPDATE` queries, eventually one DDL or a make table query and  an `INSERT` query?

Comment: The status of the .WithBracket field determines which fields in the table [Caliper Master] need to be updated.  While I'm sure it's possible to work this into the SQL, my general level of proficiency before taking on this project was "Customize minecraft and Skyrim mod .ini files", and I kinda got thrown at "Here's MS Access, build an inventory system for the company and automate our office processes."  I'm figuring this out as I go through online research and books.

Comment: Sounds like a great start of a wonderful career! :) I'm wondering if it is important to loop through the records of the form instead of using the forms recordsource directly (what's the table/query name and coumn names?). Can the form be filtered by the user? Another question: What is the intention of `ElseIf Me.WithBracket <> -1 Or 0 Or Null`? This expression for sure does not what you want.

Comment: .WithBracket is a field that carries a variant for a triple-state check box to determine if an individual part has another part with it, doesn't have the other part with it, or is solely ordering the extra part.  These quantities are stored in the [Caliper Master] table individually, and split/combined as necessary through code. That line is there basically to make sure no other values get passed through.  Although I suppose a simple "Else" would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: If *WithBracket* is a triple-state ComboBox, there can only be three cases… remove the fourth one completely and change the third one to a simple `Else`, because comparing with `Null` won't work with the *equal* comparison operator. What about my question about using the forms RecordSource table/query instead of the RecordsetClone?

Comment: Frankly, I just learned looping using recordsetclone, so I went with what worked before.  If there's a better way I'm all ears.

Comment: Oops, of course I meant *Checkbox*. Well, then we are already two that are all ears, although for different reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You loop a recordset `rs`, but you use form data like `Me.QuantityHv` when creating your sql strings.

This will always use the data from the current record on the form, i.e. the same value for every loop iteration.

Use values from `rs` instead, e.g. `rs!QuantityHv`.

Comment: This results in a compile error, method or data member not found on rs.QuantityHv.  I have the proper references for DAO methods, and the rs contains the field.

Comment: Got it.  Had to use ! rather than . in rs!QuantityHv.  Thanks!